# COM error in VS 2015, not solved by changing platform target

Tags: c#, .net, interop, office-interop

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I am trying to connect to microsoft word from a C# application (WPF), but keep getting this message. On my computer (64 bit) I have Word 2007.

The common solution to change the platform target to x86 doesn't work, I've also tried three different versions of the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word reference,  12.0.0.0, 14.0.0.0 and 15.0.0.0, all with the same error. I downloaded the 2007 PIAs, I modified VS from the installer to include Microsoft Office Developer Tools, and I'm 99% sure I have office installed (I can open and use Word):

[image: Programs and Features]

and I followed some instructions to check the registry, which stated that if the "InstallRoot" folder existed in a certain place, that means Office is installed:

[image]

I'm sure either Office or the interop references are not installed correctly, but I'm not comfortable enough navigating the registry editor to even begin checking for that.

I've been reading solutions to this error all day but it seems like each situation is very dependent on details.

---

EDIT: This is in the registry editor, same guid as the error message:
[image: guid]

Comment: In Regedit.exe navigate to HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID and verify that you see the {guid}.  If you don't then you have to repair/reinstall Office.  Most typical problem is that you changed the solution platform instead of the correct project setting.  Use Project > Properties > Build tab > Platform target = x86.

Comment: @Hans ,  I found the guid where you specified (see the image in my edit). Also, I followed your instructions for the project setting, and it is already changed to x86, I changed it earlier today. Any other advice?

Comment: Change the property both for the Debug and the Release configuration.  And get another diagnostic, use SysInternals' Process Monitor.  You'll see your program searching for that registry key and not finding it.

Comment: I changed for both debug and release, still nothing. Figuring out Process Monitor will take me all week... Thanks anyway

Comment: EVen if Office 2007 is installed it's not certain that the PIAs were. For 2007 these were optional and needed to be explicitly selected in a Custom install. Do you find the PIAs in the GAC?

Comment: @Cindy, yes I downloaded the 2007 PIAs separately when I couldn't find Interop in the reference list. They are in the GAC now

Comment: So, you've set a reference to the PIAs (version 12!), via the COM tab? And you need to remove any references you've made to the "Tools" - that's VSTO. Those will not be valid in a WPF environment. Then please show us the code that's causing the error.

Comment: @Cindy, I uninstalled and reinstalled Word and that fixed it, sorry for the trouble